# Reactjs : this.handleEdit is not a function

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am loading data from a DB into a Reactjs table. From that I want to extract out the Rowid and pass it as a parameter to handleEdit function.

Data loads OK, table generates with correct data, including the RowID movies.movieID but I can't pass data to the function.

A very easy thing to do in many languages, except I have been stuck on this for 2 days in Reactjs.

No matter what I do I get the same error "TypeError: _this3.handleEdit is not a function" on the click event.

Using reactjs in ASP.net core 2.2

```
this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);

handleEdit(id) {
    alert.show("Movie ID = " + id);
    console.log('Click happened');
}

static renderMoviesTable(allmovies) {
    return (
        <Table className="table table-striped"><thead>
            <tr><th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Plot</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
            </tr></thead><tbody>
                {allmovies.map(movies =>
                    <tr key={movies.movieID}>
                        <td><Button onClick={() => this.handleEdit(this, movies.movieID)} className="btn-info">Edit</Button></td>
                        <td>{movies.movieID}</td>
                        <td>{movies.title}</td>
                        <td>{movies.year}</td>
                        <td>{movies.plot}</td>
                        <td>{movies.genre}</td>
                    </tr>
                )};
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    );
```

Here is the entire class with unnecessary things culled

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";
import { Table } from "reactstrap";

export class FetchMovies extends Component {
static displayName = FetchMovies.name;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        allmovies: [],
        editMovie: [],
        selectedMovieID: "",
        title: "",
        year: "",
        plot: "",
        genre: "",
        isEditForm: false, //bool to check if you are editing
        loading: true
    };
       this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);

    fetch('api/Movies')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ allmovies: data, loading: false });
        });
}

handleEdit(id) {
    alert.show("Movie ID = " + id);
    console.log('Click happened');
}

static renderMoviesTable(allmovies) {
    return (
        <Table className="table table-striped"><thead>
            <tr><th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Plot</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
            </tr></thead><tbody>
                {allmovies.map(movies =>
                    <tr key={movies.movieID}>
                        <td><Button value={movies.movieID} onClick={() => this.handleEdit(movies.movieID)} className="btn-info">Edit</Button></td>
                        <td>{movies.movieID}</td>
                        <td>{movies.title}</td>
                        <td>{movies.year}</td>
                        <td>{movies.plot}</td>
                        <td>{movies.genre}</td>
                    </tr>
                )};
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    );
}


render() {
    let movieContents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading Movies...</em></p>
        : FetchMovies.renderMoviesTable(this.state.allmovies);

     const { isUser, addClicked, isEditForm, helper } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>All Movies</h1>
            {!isEditForm && movieContents}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post the entire class?

Comment: also, you could try to make the handleEdit declaration a fat arrow function and remove the `this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);` (which I believe needs to be in the constructor anyways)

Comment: You are passing `this` and `movies.movieID` into `handleEdit`? It only expects the `id`

Comment: Even without the 'this', it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it!

It's because you declared the method `renderMoviesTable` as a `static` method. Remove the key-word `static` from that method and that should do the trick and then call the function via `this.renderMoviesTable` instead

Static method don't get access to `this` like you think they would: https://medium.com/@yyang0903/static-objects-static-methods-in-es6-1c026dbb8bb1

Comment: You are magnificent!!!!!! I never knew that was a thing :-) Thanks so much! The crazy thing is I am following the prebuilt reactjs example and the FetchData example has static as well.